# Search format in rails not as per expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4

here is the code in my `(poappcontroller.rb)`

```
 def index
    @poapps =  Poapp.where(action: 'approve').pluck(:from, :invoice)
 end
```

code in the `index.html.erb`

```
   <table>
    <% @poapps.each do |poapp| %>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <%= poapp %>
      </td>
    </tr>

     <% end %>
    </table>
```

`output`

```
  ["Snehpandya", "fegd620"]
  ["Snehpandya", "bvnp1442"]
```

**Expected  output**

[image: have alook]

**Database**

[image: picture from database]

Comment: Show us a record in your `poapps` table

Comment: `@poapps.each do |from, invoice|` -> this will split the Array in two local variables

Comment: If you're going to edit your question, please show clearly what was original and what you have changed. Otherwise later readers will find it very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.pluck(:from, :invoice)` returns an *array of arrays*.
So, `@poapps` looks something like :

```
[["Snehpandya", "fegd620"],["Snehpandya", "bvnp1442"]]
```

which is why when you do `<%= poapp %>`, you get output as an array `["Snehpandya", "fegd620"]`

To display it in `snehpandya fegd62` format, change `index.html.erb` as below:

```
   <table>
    <% @poapps.each do |poapp| %>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <%= poapp.join(" ") %>  <!-- This will return a string connecting all elements of array with a space-->
      </td>
    </tr>

     <% end %>
    </table>
```

**UPDATE**

To get the *changed output* as shown in the image attached in the question. You can do something like this:

As suggested by MrYoshiji

```
   <table>
    <% @poapps.each do |from, invoice| %>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <%= from %> 
      </td>
      <td> 
        <%= invoice %> 
      </td>
    </tr>

     <% end %>
    </table>
```

Comment: undefined method `join' for "fegd620":String ..this what i get

Comment: Copy the code exactly. Don't merge it with Baloo's answer.

Comment: Thanks kirti but i can only see the `invoice` ..`from` is not displaying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50802/discussion-between-sneh-pandya-and-kirti-thorat)

Answer (score 1):

[Pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) returns an array, if selecting multiple items it'll return an array of arrays.  So you'll need to loop through them

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Invoice</th>
     <th>From</th>
   </tr>
   <% @poapps.each do |poapp| %>

   <tr>
     <%= poapp.each do |poapp_content| %>
       <td> 
         <%= poapp_content %>
       </td>
     <% end %>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Updated, but you should accept Kirti Thorat's answer as she gave you the output you originally requested, and again this time now you've changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= poapp.join(" ") %>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: That's because he's changed his question since i answered it.  When i answered it, this answer was correct.

Comment: As a matter of style, one line answers are not a good idea. If you have so little to say then maybe a comment is enough.

Comment: Is that a stackoverflow policy?  "If you can answer the question succinctly, then you shouldn't do it as an answer, you should do it as a comment"?

Comment: The policy is that both questions and answers should be of high quality, such that they will benefit other readers. The practice is that people who know the answer but couldn't be bothered to spend the time to write a full answer often add a short comment instead. Your answer came to me through the review queue as low quality. If you want to avoid that, either submit as a comment or write longer answers. But with your rep you should know all that.